# Почему вылетает программа, при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Почему когда нажимаю на кнопку "**`Kонвертировать`**" закрывает программу?

Что я делаю не так? Укажите пожалуйста на ошибку.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter


class CurrencyConv(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CurrencyConv, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Конвертер валют')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('exchanging.png'))
        self.ui.input_currency.setPlaceholderText('Из валюты:')
        self.ui.input_amount.setPlaceholderText('У меня есть:')
        self.ui.output_currency.setPlaceholderText('В валюту:')
        self.ui.output_amount.setPlaceholderText('Я получу:')
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.converter)

    def converter(self):
        c = CurrencyConverter()
        input_currency = self.ui.input_currency.text()
        output_currency = self.ui.output_currency.text()
        input_amount = int(self.ui.input_amount.text())
        output_amount = c.convert(input_amount, '%s' % (input_currency), '%s' % (output_currency))
        self.ui.output_amount.setText(str(output_amount))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = CurrencyConv()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(480, 755)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color:")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.input_amount = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_amount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 400, 380, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.input_amount.setFont(font)
        self.input_amount.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;\n"
"border: 2px solid #f66867;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: white;")
        self.input_amount.setText("")
        self.input_amount.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_amount.setObjectName("input_amount")
        self.output_amount = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_amount.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 560, 380, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.output_amount.setFont(font)
        self.output_amount.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;\n"
"border: 2px solid #f66867;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: white;")
        self.output_amount.setText("")
        self.output_amount.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.output_amount.setObjectName("output_amount")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 660, 380, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: #fb5b5d;\n"
"    border-radius: 30;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    background-color: #fa4244;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 480, 271))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: #fb5b5d")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 80, 191, 171))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("exchanging.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 331, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: white;\n"
"")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.input_currency = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_currency.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 320, 380, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.input_currency.setFont(font)
        self.input_currency.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;\n"
"border: 2px solid #f66867;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: white;")
        self.input_currency.setText("")
        self.input_currency.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_currency.setObjectName("input_currency")
        self.output_currency = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_currency.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 480, 380, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Montserrat")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.output_currency.setFont(font)
        self.output_currency.setStyleSheet("background-color: #22222e;\n"
"border: 2px solid #f66867;\n"
"border-radius: 30;\n"
"color: white;")
        self.output_currency.setText("")
        self.output_currency.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.output_currency.setObjectName("output_currency")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КОНВЕРТИРУЙ"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "КОНВЕРТЕР ВАЛЮТ"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А возникает какая-то при этом ошибка? Или просто вылетает?

Comment: @Tehnorobot В консоли выдает `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`

Comment: Посмотри здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604689/pycharm-error-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073740791-0xc0000409

Comment: вы пробовали запускать приложение в терминале/консоли/CMD?

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаком с модулем **`currency_converter`**.

Чтобы получить реальную ошибку запустите приложение в терминале/консоли/CMD.

Ну и предложу попробовать заменить метод `converter()`  так:

```
import currency_converter
...

    ...
    def converter(self):
        self.c = CurrencyConverter()
        input_currency = self.ui.input_currency.text()
        output_currency = self.ui.output_currency.text()
        input_amount = int(self.ui.input_amount.text())
        
        try:
            output_amount = self.c.convert(
                input_amount, 
                input_currency, 
                output_currency
            )
        except currency_converter.currency_converter.RateNotFoundError:
            print("Error not found")
        else:
            self.ui.output_amount.setText(str(output_amount))
    ...
```

Comment: @Ilya что не так?